# Changing mouse appearance at notebook level

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, customization

Ideally, I'd like to change the mouse pointer appearance(s) at notebook level, from a styleseet. However, I'd be satisfied only by changing its color. 
This is the main issue keepeing me away from dark themes: the pointer becomes hard to find.

There seems to be an option "MousePointerAppearance" but I don't know how/if it works.

Comment: where do you see this option?

Comment: @acl in the option inspector under Editing options, v10

Comment: This almost gets there, but the mouse style resets if you click or move away from the notebook. ``FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`SetMouseAppearance[Graphics@{Red, Text@"x"}]]``

Comment: @mfvonh nice attempt

Comment: Try [singing a nice song](http://letras.mus.br/celedonio-flores/795203/)

Comment: @belisarius, put that as an answer, so I can downvote it

Comment: @Rojo I've started to translate the verse. At this pace it'll be ready by Mma v14. You may want to start by downvoting some of my already posted answers to avoid wasting your rage

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of: [(1631)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1631/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so, what to do then?

Comment: @Kuba Did you vote to close?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no, I don't know which is better to stay, since there is no accepted answer maybe a merge?

Comment: @Kuba I always favor keeping the older post as primary unless the new one is strongly superior.  If we close in that direction I'll ask Silvia if a merge is desired.

Answer (score 5):

A little improvement according to [mfvonh's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55126/changing-mouse-appearance-at-notebook-level#comment158518_55126):

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], Background -> GrayLevel[0]]
SetOptions[
           InputNotebook[],
           NotebookEventActions -> {
                   "MouseClicked" :> 
                          FrontEndExecute[ FrontEnd`SetMouseAppearance[
                                     Dynamic@Style["\[Earth]", "Graphics", 30, Hue[Clock[]]]
                                                                      ]],
                   PassEventsDown -> True
                                   }
          ]
```

Sadly `"MouseEntered"` or `"MouseOver"` are both not working here.

Comment: Nice idea Silvia, +1. However, the Graphics background seems to be non-transparent if I put the notebook background black

Comment: @Rojo Try my new improvement please :)

Comment: Nice icon, it feels like I am about to shoot at the code. It can be seen in any background :P (even in this `SetOptions[InputNotebook[], Background -> Dynamic@Hue@Clock[]]`).

Comment: Strange, when I just change to "LinkHand" it switches when I move cursor out of the window, but yours pointer keeps it's value.

Comment: @Kuba Have you tried moving the cursor fast enough so it won't trig the "cross window boarder" event?