# How to get a larger mouse cursor

Tags: front-end

I'm giving a presentation with Mathematica and want to point to things with my mouse so want the cursor to be nice and big. I've changed my cursor to be nice and big in Windows (8.1), but when I go to Mathematica, I get the standard, small cursor. Is there any way to change this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps [`MouseAppearance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MouseAppearance.html) may help.

Comment: If OS settings/external tools are not working then we are out of luck because it seems you can't do that in stable way: [Changing mouse appearance at notebook level](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55126/5478)

Comment: You could use a third party program such as Yolomouse.

Comment: @Kuba, I saw that post but didn't understand it and thought it wasn't what I wanted. Then I clicked on more comments to find the following post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/changing-the-mouseappearance-on-the-entire-notebook-front-end which, after some tweaking, was good enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So how should I put this post to an end?

Comment: @user46348 I wouldn't use the latter method. It messes with the output, everything then will be wrapped with `MouseAppearance` like you would've done this manually. Normally evaluation of those two lines, `True`, `TrueQ @ %` gives `True` and `True`. After applying that methodthe latter one will be False while both will be still wrapped with `MouseAppearance` anyway.